# Angular TestBed.inject type error when injecting into a spy

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

I want to inject a service into a serviceSpy in the same way as the angular example shows.
Angular 9
https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

```
let masterService: MasterService;
let valueServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ValueService>;

beforeEach(() => {
const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ValueService', ['getValue']);

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
// Provide both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
providers: [
  MasterService,
  { provide: ValueService, useValue: spy }
]
});
// Inject both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
masterService = TestBed.inject(MasterService);
valueServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(ValueService);
});
```

intellij shows me this error
TS2322: Type 'ValueService' is not assignable to type 
    `SpyObj<ValueService>`

can someone help?

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue. Accordingly to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35944 you may

```
valueServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(ValueService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ValueService>;
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: Seems to be bad function typing by Angular, as the `.inject()` returns `T` and not `SpyObj<T>`. But thank you for the valid type cast hint.

Comment: Keep in mind that, the syntax `as` or `<T>` in this case is an **assertion** and not **casting** https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have found a solution to this yet, but I just faced the same issue and someone explained it to me - you have to cast it as unknown first and then cast it as something specific. So you'd eliminate any TS errors if you do this:

```
valueServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(ValueService) as unknown as jasmine.SpyObj<ValueService>;
```

You're basically saying "I am about to pass a type that you don't know, but I want you to treat it as type blah blah". That's my understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `{ provide: ValueService, useValue: spy as any }`

Comment: didnt help; testService = TestBed.inject(TestService); is the problem...

Comment: Shouldn't be `TestBed.get(TestService)`, `TestBed.get(MasterService)`, `TestBed.get(ValueService)`?

Comment: deprecated and replaced with inject https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#get